# dateRangeInput R Shiny Control Alignment

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to align `dateRangeInput` control in R Shiny for a while now(more than `2`hours) but still not able to do so. I've also searched Stackoverflow and found solutions that conveniently does the job for other controls, such as textInput or numericInput. But, when it comes to `dateRangeInput` what I've seen so far fail. Please if someone could help me with this, I'd appreciate. Following is a stand-alone code(also picked up from Stackoverflow):

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
      tags$form(
        class="form-horizontal",
        tags$div(
          class="form-group",
          tags$label(class = "col-sm-4 control-label", `for` = "Area1000", "Area"),
          column(width = 4, dateRangeInput("date_range", label="", start="1900-01-01",
                                                                end ="2099-12-31",
                                                                min    = "1900-01-01",
                                                                max    = "2099-12-31"))
        )
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you describe what the expecetd output would be?

Comment: Label and control should be horizontally aligned. They are not properly aligned now. If you notice date control is a little below the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an empty label being created by the dateRangeInput (as documented at: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/dateRangeInput.html)

> label: Display label for the control, or NULL for no label.

So if you used dateRangeInput("date_range", label = NULL ... your current code should work.

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           tags$form(
             class="form-horizontal",
             tags$div(
               class="form-group",
               tags$label(class = "col-sm-4 control-label", `for` = "date_range", "Area"),
               column(width = 4, dateRangeInput("date_range", label = NULL, start="1900-01-01",
                                                end ="2099-12-31",
                                                min    = "1900-01-01",
                                                max    = "2099-12-31"))
             )
           )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would also change the `for` declaration to `date_range` to match the id on the date range input element.